# Database design for dictionary site

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

For a single language dictionary with about 10k words on it, where some words are repeated but with different meaning, would it be ok to use a single table design?

```
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id         | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| word       | varchar(128) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| definition | varchar(500) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| example    | text         | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| date       | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| votes      | int(4)       | NO   |     | 0       |                |
| name       | varchar(30)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Example queries im using:

```
SELECT * FROM definitions WHERE word = ? ORDER BY votes DESC LIMIT 10
SELECT word, definition FROM definitions ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 4
SELECT DISTINCT word FROM definitions WHERE word LIKE ? LIMIT 100
```

Also the votes row get updated everytime someone votes.

Would be better to have a one-to-many design instead? My main goal is performance.

Comment: with 10j row and only some doubled no, if you need the words for something else and don't mind joining go ahead

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--including cut & paste & runnable minimal code & minimal representative data given as code. For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL, including constraints, indexes & tabular initialization. For SQL performance that includes EXPLAIN results & statistics. Please research & summarize. For SQL that includes basics of optimization/performance--immediately leading to indexes, plans, statistics & SARGability. [Tips for asking a good SQL question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/3404097) Ask re optimization after you have learned & applied those basics. [ask]

Answer (score 0):

your table looks like it would be stable and only searching will be performed on it.
the only column that will cause the table to perform insert or update operation may affect your performance. You should only get the votes to other table along with word id. whenever a vote is inserted , it will not perform insert operation on your main table. that will increase your table performance in longer terms.
Select data from both table using join.

Answer (score 0):

For only 10K words (or did you mean rows), and those queries, performance will be 'good enough'.  However, these are needed:

```
INDEX(date)
INDEX(word, votes)
```

Hint..  If new definitions will come in often, then `ORDER BY votes DESC LIMIT 10` will tend to not show them (when there are more than 10).  So, you should probably have some formula involving the date at which the definition was added and the number of votes.  It might be something like `votes / TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, date, NOW())` or to temper it: `(votes + 1) / DATEDIFF(DAY, date, NOW() + INTERVAL 2 DAY)`.  That would go in the `ORDER BY`.